# Plural meaning of the word

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a function that outputs the translation of a word when the number is 1, and the number is greater than one.
Please help me make a function that will output a translation for each number, for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11, etc.

```
enter code here
                                <div class="tour_attribute_rating_count">
                                    <?php echo intval($overall_rating_count); ?>&nbsp;
                                    <?php
                                        if($overall_rating_count > 1)
                                        {
                                            echo esc_html__('reviews', 'grandtour' );
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            echo esc_html__('review', 'grandtour' );
                                        }
                                    ?>
enter code here
```

Comment: Checkout this guide on the subject: http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/localization-guide/en/latest/guide/plurals_programmers.html

Comment: well, unfortunately, the author of the topic did not want to include i18n in the PO file. Configure it yourself for "%n form 1\n"
"%n form 2\n"
"%n form 3" I tried, but all my attempts were in vain. Also wrote to the author of the topic, he just ignores. That's why I turned to the forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this:

```
function singularPluralText($number, $singular, $plural) {
  $output = $number . ' ';
  if ($number == 1) {
    $output .= esc_html__($singular, 'grandtour');
  }
  else if ($number > 1) {
    $output .= esc_html__($plural, 'grandtour');
  }

  return $output;
}
```

And use it in your html like this:

```
<div class="tour_attribute_rating_count">
  <?php echo singularPluralText(intval($overall_rating_count), 'review', 'reviews'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: nothing happened by adding this code, you did not understand my request a little, I do not want to present this code in another form, I want to add a multiple translation depending on the numeral before the word manually, since i18n is not available in the PO file.

Answer (score 0):

Можно ли перевести переменную в блоке:

2 
 отзывов

Которая отвечает за количество отзывов и берёт перевод темы

Используя такую функцию:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function ( $strings ) {
/**
 * Holding translations/changes.
 * 'to translate' => 'the translation or rewording'
 */
$text = array(
    '2 отзывов' => '2 отзыва',
    '2&nbspотзывов'=>'2 отзыва',
    '2&nbsp отзывов'=>'2 отзыва'
);
$strings = str_ireplace( array_keys( $text ), $text, $strings );
return $strings;
```

}, 20 );

Конкретно с ней не помогло, возможно где то ошибку допустил? ((((